# Virtual Reality SDK Oculus failed to initialize

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Usually the Unity error "Virtual Reality SDK Oculus failed to initialize" goes away if I do one or more of the following:

- Restart Oculus Home
- Restart Unity
- Unplug and re-plugin the headset
- Reboot the computer

However, this time none of the above worked for me. I don't seem to find any logs or anything that could hint what is causing the error.

What troubles me is that my project was working 100% fine. I only made a few property changes to my scene and custom Prefabs which were unrelated to any VR stuff and suddenly when I press the "Play" button I get this error. Undoing my latest changes also made no difference.

Is there a proper way to troubleshoot this error or something else that anyone could suggest to try?

Comment: In addition to what you've already tried you can also remove the oculus package and then load it back in again. This sometimes fixes it for me

Comment: In addition I also tried the following, but without any success:
Upgraded the Oculus Package from the Package Manager; Re-imported the Oculus Integration from the Asset Store;
Deleted the "Library" folder in Unity and let it regenerate all the files again

Comment: I just noticed that the exact same error also occur on previous projects that used to work 100%.

Comment: But if you set up a new project, it works as expected?

Comment: @nrs It actually worked! No idea what is different as both projects are setup the same as far as I can tell. If you convert your comment to an answer and possibly add why you think it made a difference, I will accept it. Also I was hoping for a better solution because to recreate each broken project is very time consuming.